# Of ten fifty-peso bills, three are counterfeit. Six bills are chosen.

Tags: probability

Of ten fifty-peso bills, three are counterfeit. Six bills are chosen at random. What is the probability that
all counterfeit bills are chosen?

I tried solving for the number of ways the six bills could be rearranged if three counterfeit bills and three genuine bills are chosen, which is 20, but I don't know how to move on from there.

Answer (score 3):

The probability that the first bill chosen is counterfeit is $\frac{3}{10}$. Given that the first bill chosen was counterfeit, the probability that the second is also counterfeit is $\frac{2}{9}$. Given that the first and second were counterfeit, the probability that the third is counterfeit is $\frac{1}{8}$. Therefore, the probability that, when $6$ bills are chosen, the first $3$ are counterfeit is $\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{8}$. There are ${6\choose 3}=20$ ways of rearranging a sequence of $6$ bills, $3$ of which are counterfeit, so the probability that all $3$ counterfeit bills are chosen is
$$20\cdot\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{6}=0.1\dot{6}.$$

Answer (score 3):

There are $\binom33=1$ ways to choose $3$ counterfeit bills out of $3$ counterfeit bills.

There are $\binom73=35$ ways to choose $3$ non-counterfeit bills out of $7$ non-counterfeit bills.

There are $\binom{10}6=210$ ways to choose $6$ bills out of $10$ bills.

This makes us find: $$\frac{\binom33\binom73}{\binom{10}6}=\frac{35}{210}=\frac16$$ as the probability that $3$ counterfeit bills are chosen.